# Spring boot application.yaml invalid value

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra

i ve got an application.yaml file with :

```
spring:
  cassandra:
    contact-points: ${spring.cassandra.contact-points}
    port: ${spring.cassandra.port}
```

I am planning to have dinamic variables for the Cassandra testcontainers.

but receive an error in application.yaml file: "Invalid value , must be of type 'java.lang.integer'"

how to resolve this mistake?

Comment: Why? Just pass `spring.cassandra.contact-points` as variable you don't need to add anything to the `application.yaml`.

Comment: Does it wright just to leave as above?

Comment: No as it fails (as you noticed), next to that you are referencing the same properties so it creates a cycle. So no it is not right next to being unnecessary.

Comment: i ve changed variable to ${cassandra.port} to avoid cycle. but reference to 'java.lang.integer' still showed

Comment: Because that isn't an integer. But it is all not needed, why do you want to add complexity? You also state test containers which dynamic properties are supported out-of-the-box so you don't need to do anything for that. Seems more like you are trying to work around the features of the framework.